# Why is ngSrc needed for images and not other elements?

Tags: angularjs

The official AngularJS tutorial states that ngSrc

> prevents the browser from treating the Angular {{ expression }} markup
>   literally, and initiating a request to an invalid URL

But why is this needed for specifically for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the browser will interpret the dom before angularjs could rewrite the url, and would try to load the resource literally called `{{ expression }}`, which is of course an error, as it is not even a url. Use `ngSrc`, and angular will fill the `src` attribute of the `img` tag as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer...

> The issue here is that the browser will fire a request for that
>   invalid image address as soon as it hits the img tag, which is before
>   Angular has a chance to evaluate the expression and inject the valid
>   address.

Answer (score 0):

When you use src and expression it is not parsable:

```
<img src="{{expression}}" alt="" />
```

Will result in error for its file path.

But using ngSrc the expression is parsed by angularjs and the value of the expression like url would be parsed and displayed as final result in html:

```
<img src="{{expression}}" alt="" />
```

Will result in url of its file path depending on your expression and this will be something like this:

```
<img src="images/path.jpg" alt="" />
```